# ArrayInput with SimpleFormIterator and conditional inputs

Tags: react-admin

Let's say I have the following array in my create form

```
    const CreateDefaults = {Inputs: [{id: "ID1", param: "a"},{id: "ID2", param: "b"}]};
```

and then I want to show extra `TextInput` only when `id==="ID2"`

```
export const MyCreate = withStyles(myStyles)(({ classes, ...props }) => (
<Create {...props}>
  <SimpleForm defaultValue={CreateDefaults}>
    <ArrayInput source="Inputs" {...props}>
      <SimpleFormIterator {...props}>
        <DisabledInput source="id" />
        {/*this does not work*/}
        {this.id === "ID2" ? (<TextInput source="ParamValue"/>) :null}
      </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
  </SimpleForm>
</Create>
));
```

How can I do something like that? I know that for the whole form, one can use `FormDataConsumer`. However, what can one do inside `ArrayInput/SimpleFormIterator` for each iteration?

How to access current object in iteration? I tried something like [the answer given to the 'Custom Input do not receive record when inside ArrayInput' issue in the react-admin github page](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1783), but it still does not receive the record in custom input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest documentation [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs), you can see that if you use `FormDataConsumer` that is within an `ArrayInput`, you have a parameter called `scopedFormData` that you can use to get the current record and dereference that to get whatever fields you need. It usually also goes hand in hand with the `getSource` function you can use when setting the source within your `FormDataConsumer`.